# How to detect the motion of a shape (blob) from scratch (in c, not using openCv)

Tags: c, embedded, motion, motion-detection

I get a 22x22 image every 100ms and applied a threshold to isolate the target. I tracked the center of the object/shape/blob.
I now want to detect a motion.

My first thought was to keep track of the past 2 seconds (20 frames) and compare the center of the frames to see if there is a constant delta.

Or even simpler compare the center to the center 2 seconds ago.

This approach seems too simple, sub-optimal, and prone to issues.

Do you have links to how to detect motion "from scratch" to keep it lightweight?

Comment: Your target may be embedded, but there is nothing specific to embedded in your question.  You could broaden your audience by removing that tag.  With such a small image, what is the need for "optimisation".  What specifically is sub-oprtimal about your current proposal.  Have you tried it?  That would be the best way of assessing its performance and making this improvements.  You are confusing ""simple" with "simplistic".  The simplest solution is likely to be the best, while a _simplistic_ solution is flawed.

Comment: Your concern seems unfounded, difference between frames _is_ only indicator of motion available to you (or an AI for that matter).  Why however should there be a _constant_ delta over 20 frames?  That would require constant velocity, and at 22 pixels, anything moving at constant delta for 20 frames is likely to no longer be in the frame!

Comment: More like information required, such as can the shape rotate or only translate? Are you tracking only translation, or orientation also?  Rather than describing a solution you have considered, code that solution and post the code.  You say you have thresholded and tracked the centre, you might also post that code.

Comment: Your only question here is to request a link to a solution.  You cannot ask for that on SO. Link-only answers are bad form.  You have to ask for an actual solution right here.

Comment: One and only one shape, or multiple?

Comment: @Clifford I mentionned embedded so that people understand why I cannot use OpenCv (too heavy) but yes I could remove the tag. No, I haven't tried it, I was waiting for someone's input to see if there is a known algorithm that does the job well. You are right.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of saving the 20 last frames but comparing the delta between every 5 frames. Saving only the last 10 frames and comparing the firsta dn last one could be a solution (simple).

Comment: No rotation required. I thaught about posting some code but since it is embedded, there is no minimal working code that I can post without doing a bunch of modifications especially since I fetch the data of a sensor, making a code simulation the behavior of the sensor would be bigger than the mnimal working code for the center tracking and direction detection.

Comment: Feel free to exmplain it to me by text ^^ . I often see people explaining something briefly and linking an article/exemple way more detailed, that was my targetted answer there. Ye, SO is very (too) strict about the style of questions and answers.

Comment: Only one so far, I thought about multiple but I will try to keep it as simple as possible yet.

Comment: Some code to illustrate your algorithm, is probably better than no does even if no one can directly run it.  The "minimal working code" thing is useful when you want a semantic or syntax correction, but that is not what you are asking.

Comment: It sounds like a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) might be what you want, but I don't know if it is "light" enough for your needs. It's popular for tracking objects (that might become obscured) in AI applications.